# Не понимаю почему в setInetrval внутри useEffect добавляет undefined к результирующей строке

Tags: reactjs

Не понимаю почему **useEffect**, внутри которого запускается **setInterval** добавляет **undefined**?

Подозреваю что он добавляет цифру(индекс элемента символа в строке) под конец, но я думаю что я ошибаюсь потому что плохо знаком с js.

```
const [reception, setReception] = useState(''); 
const textNumOne = 'text one';

useEffect(() => {
    let iText = 0;
    const functionText = setInterval(() => {
        iText++
        setReception(prev => prev + textNumOne[iText])
        if (iText >= textNumOne.length) clearInterval(functionText)
    }, 
        150
    );
}, []);

console.log(reception)
```

Comment: `if(iText == textNumOne.length - 1) clearInterval(...)`

Comment: Интересная штука получается, сейчас попробую описать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### На React 18.2 в [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/schetchik-e5kes0?file=/src/App.js) происходят интересные вещи

А именно, если делать внешний счетчик по отношению к функции изменения состояния, то 2я(индекс 1) итерация пропускается, хотя увеличение счетчика идет по порядку.

Как работает не совсем корректно:

```
  const textNumOne = "123456789";

  useEffect(() => {
    let iText = 0;
    const functionText = setInterval(() => {
      setReception((prev) => {
        return prev + textNumOne[iText];
      });
      iText++;
      if (iText >= textNumOne.length - 1) clearInterval(functionText);
    }, 150);
  }, []);
```

Вывод: **13456789**

Мои предложения по реализации данного вывода:

> **Создать отдельную функцию, в которую передавать индекс элемента для изменения состояния**

```
  const textNumOne = "123456789";

  useEffect(() => {
    let iText = 0;
    const incer = (pos) => {
      setReception((prev) => {
        return prev + textNumOne[pos];
      });
    };
    const functionText = setInterval(() => {
      incer(iText);
      iText++;
      if (iText >= textNumOne.length) clearInterval(functionText);
    }, 150);
  }, []);
```

Вывод: **123456789**

> **Изменять счетчик внутри функции изменения состояния**

```
  const textNumOne = "123456789";

  useEffect(() => {
    let iText = 0;
    const functionText = setInterval(() => {
      setReception((prev) => {
        iText++;
        return prev + textNumOne[iText - 1];
      });

      if (iText >= textNumOne.length - 1) clearInterval(functionText);
    }, 150);
  }, []);
```

Вывод: **123456789**

Comment: Интересный кейс. Но не очень понимаю, почему 2-я итерация пропускается

Comment: @Александр Знал бы сам, поведал бы. В консоли, если выводить, то счетчик тикает как надо, а вот `set*` пропускает значение... Пока особо не ковырял это. Еще хотел проверить на других версиях реакта, но пока руки не дошли до такого исследования